# Compress 19 digits to BASE36 10 alphanumeric

Tags: compression, cobol

Working in Cobol and having a 18 digit number I need to convert into 10 Alphanumeric BASE36 (15 digits). It is possible in BASE 80 but I only got 10 bytes available in upper case... To reduce the 18 digits I can use another known number between 000000001 and 9999999999 (it's an account number of 10 digits with modulus in last ciffer) so I'm left with basically no compression Any ideas? I have to convert back to the original number...

Comment: Bases are just simple remainders when dividing the decimal number by the base. If you are compressing, you don't need bother about the compressed value being human-readable unless you have some need. Why do you want to do this, and what volumes are you talking about. Also COBOL version and OS would be useful. Put as much information in the question as possible (use the edit link under the question) else you'll get poorer answers.

Comment: What the heck. If you need characters to represent a base, you have uppercase, lowecase, and "special" characters "(shift and the numbers gives you 10 more, I have a further 12 non-alpha/numeric keys on my keyboard, which can be shifted, and a few more available with alt-gr). If it is not going anywhere, so no need to be readable encoded, how about just storing at as packed-decimal (19 digits fits in 10 bytes) or binary (18 digits fits in eight bytes).

Comment: What does this mean: "To reduce the 18 digits I can use another known number between 000000001 and 9999999999 (it's an account number of 10 digits with modulus in last ciffer)"

Comment: Can you clarify the question please. What does the 10 digit account number have to do with the 18 digit number ?. Also it would take 12 digit (base 32 or 36) to represent an 18 digit number, not 15

Comment: @BruceMartin No, he's saying that a 10-digit base 36 number is able to represent a 15-digit decimal number. That's where the 15 comes from. Somehow he wants to magically fit into 10 base-36 digits what would take 12 base-36 digits. Like you, I do not understand what the 10-digit account number has to do with anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. 36<sup>10</sup> is much less than 10<sup>19</sup> (or 10<sup>18</sup>, which is it?), so it is not possible to represent all 19 or 18-digit numbers in base 10 with 10-digit numbers in base 36.

Comment: It is COBOL. There is entirely zero problem with storing 19 (or 18) digits in 10 bytes, natively. Indeed, there is no problem in doing it in eight bytes. Is the implicit requirement to be "readable" an issue (transfer from Mainframe to non-Mainframe with different encoding, for instance) when there's up to 96 characters available. How helpful, without giving a chance to OP to expand, is "you can't do it"? At least it got a vote.

Comment: The OP didn't say 10 bytes. The OP said 10 base-36 digits, i.e. only digit and capital letter characters. The question is quite explicit about what is allowed. That cannot be done, mathematically. The OP now has enough information to look at the 36 in 36^10 and figure out what it would need to be. The question already acknowledges that it would be possible with more characters (80), but asks if it can be done with 36. The answer is no. (The OP would need 64 characters to choose from, for 18 digits. Though the OP is not clear on how many digits actually need to be encoded.)

Comment: "but I only got 10 bytes available". OK, the lack of clarity in the question makes it open to interpretation. Already states in the question that it is only possible for 15 digits for base 36. Doesn't seem to stop them wanting to do something, though it is yet unclear as to what. You are pointing out what is already stated (arguably, perhaps, but I think at least that is clear) in the question. You are correct, but OP knows it already.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark. You may know this, but here is the base anything to base 10 conversion formula. Lets say you have a number 45678 for my simplicity reasons. Start with the value of the digit on the right. Add it to the digit to it's left * base, increasing with the base power:

```
8+(7*36)+(6*36*36)+(5*36*36*36)+(4*36*36*36*36) = 6959780 base 10
```

Of course, you may have to make code to recognize characters as numerical values. Hence, my simplicity.

Comment: OK, but this is the "wrong way around". It needs to go *to* base 36.